# Find coincidence and add column

Tags: python, regex, data-processing

I want to achieve this specific task, I have 2 files, the first one with emails and credentials:

```
xavier.desprez@william.com:Xavier
xavier.locqueneux@william.com:vocojydu
xaviere.chevry@pepe.com:voluzigy
Xavier.Therin@william.com:Pussycat5
xiomara.rivera@william.com:xrhj1971
xiomara.rivera@william-honduras.william.com:xrhj1971
```

and the second one, with emails and location:

```
xavier.desprez@william.com:BOSNIA
xaviere.chevry@pepe.com:ROMANIA
```

I want that, whenever the email from the first file is found on the second file, the row is substituted by EMAIL:CREDENTIAL:LOCATION , and when it is not found, it ends up being: EMAIL:CREDENTIAL:BLANK

so the final file must be like this:

```
xavier.desprez@william.com:Xavier:BOSNIA
xavier.locqueneux@william.com:vocojydu:BLANK
xaviere.chevry@pepe.com:voluzigy:ROMANIA
Xavier.Therin@william.com:Pussycat5:BLANK
xiomara.rivera@william.com:xrhj1971:BLANK
xiomara.rivera@william-honduras.william.com:xrhj1971:BLANK
```

I have do several tries in python, but it is not even worth it to write it because I am not really close to the solution.

Regards !

EDIT:

This is what I tried:

```
import os
import sys


with open("test.txt", "r") as a_file:

  for line_a in a_file:

   stripped_email_a = line_a.strip().split(':')[0]


   with open("location.txt", "r") as b_file:


        for line_b in b_file:

          stripped_email_b = line_b.strip().split(':')[0]
          location = line_b.strip().split(':')[1]

          if stripped_email_a == stripped_email_b:
            a = line_a + ":" + location
            print(a.replace("\n",""))
          else:
            b = line_a + ":BLANK"
            print (b.replace("\n",""))
```

This is the result I get:

```
xavier.desprez@william.com:Xavier:BOSNIA
xavier.desprez@william.com:Xavier:BLANK
xaviere.chevry@pepe.com:voluzigy:BLANK
xaviere.chevry@pepe.com:voluzigy:ROMANIA
xavier.locqueneux@william.com:vocojydu:BLANK
xavier.locqueneux@william.com:vocojydu:BLANK
Xavier.Therin@william.com:Pussycat5:BLANK
Xavier.Therin@william.com:Pussycat5:BLANK
xiomara.rivera@william.com:xrhj1971:BLANK
xiomara.rivera@william.com:xrhj1971:BLANK
xiomara.rivera@william-honduras.william.com:xrhj1971:BLANK
xiomara.rivera@william-honduras.william.com:xrhj1971:BLANK
```

I am very close but I get duplicates ;)

Regards

Comment: I edited my question, that was what I tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The duplication issue comes from the fact that you are reading two files in a nested way, once a line from the `test.txt` is read, you open the `location.txt` file for reading and process it. Then, you read the second line from `test.txt`, and re-open the `location.txt` and process it again.

Instead, get all the necessary data from the `location.txt`, say, into a dictionary, and then use it while reading the `test.txt`:

```py
email_loc_dict = {}
with open("location.txt", "r") as b_file:
    for line_b in b_file:
        splits = line_b.strip().split(':')
        email_loc_dict[splits[0]] = splits[1]

with open("test.txt", "r") as a_file:
    for line_a in a_file:
        line_a = line_a.strip()
        stripped_email_a = line_a.split(':')[0]
        if stripped_email_a in email_loc_dict:
            a = line_a + ":" + email_loc_dict[stripped_email_a]
            print(a)
        else:
            b = line_a + ":BLANK"
            print(b)
```

Output:

```
xavier.desprez@william.com:Xavier:BOSNIA
xavier.locqueneux@william.com:vocojydu:BLANK
xaviere.chevry@pepe.com:voluzigy:ROMANIA
Xavier.Therin@william.com:Pussycat5:BLANK
xiomara.rivera@william.com:xrhj1971:BLANK
xiomara.rivera@william-honduras.william.com:xrhj1971:BLANK
```